# Spring boot starter minio gives error "bean of type that could not be found " for spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, minio

I am trying to upgrade my spring boot application to the spring boot 3 and I am getting error regrading minio. Below you can find find files from my project.

build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory")
    implementation("com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-actuator")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    implementation("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6")
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.4.0.Final")
    implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.2")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    runtimeOnly("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")


    //implementation("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect")
    implementation(files("libs/jconn4.jar"))
    //implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose")
    implementation("com.jlefebure:spring-boot-starter-minio:1.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("de.cronn:test-utils:0.9.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv")
    implementation("org.webjars:bootstrap:5.3.0")
    implementation("org.webjars:jquery:3.6.0")
    implementation("org.webjars:jquery-validation:1.19.3")
    implementation("org.webjars.npm:swiper:8.3.2")
    implementation("org.webjars.npm:panzoom__panzoom:4.5.1")
    implementation("org.webjars.npm:notiflix:3.2.5")
    implementation("org.webjars:selectize.js:0.12.4")
    implementation("org.webjars:select2:4.0.13")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.14.1")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.1")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.1.0")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3")
}
```

config.kt

```
package se.astrego.centralDatabase

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import se.astrego.centralDatabase.repositories.AssayRepository
import se.astrego.centralDatabase.repositories.enteties.Assay
import se.astrego.centralDatabase.repositories.enteties.FinalQcAssayRepo
import se.astrego.centralDatabase.services.AssayService
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.*


@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
class Config @Autowired constructor(
    val repository: AssayRepository,
    val assayService: AssayService,
    val finalQcAssayRepo: FinalQcAssayRepo
) {

    //my code
}
```

CentralDatabaseApplication.kt

```
package se.astrego.centralDatabase

import org.apache.catalina.Context
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("se.astrego.centralDatabase.services.monitor")
class CentralDatabaseApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<CentralDatabaseApplication>(*args)
}

@Component
class ServletConfig(){
    @Bean
    fun servletContainer(): ServletWebServerFactory? {
        val tomcat: TomcatServletWebServerFactory = object : TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            override fun postProcessContext(context: Context) {
                val securityConstraint = SecurityConstraint()
                securityConstraint.userConstraint = "CONFIDENTIAL"
                val collection = SecurityCollection()
                collection.addPattern("/*")
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection)
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint)
            }
        }
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector())
        return tomcat
    }

    fun redirectConnector(): Connector {
        val connector = Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol")
        connector.scheme = "http"
        connector.port = 8080
        connector.secure = false
        connector.redirectPort = 8443
        return connector
    }
}
```

FileApiController.kt

```
package se.astrego.centralDatabase.apiControllers


import com.jlefebure.spring.boot.minio.MinioService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
import se.astrego.centralDatabase.apiControllers.DTOs.FileMetadata
import se.astrego.centralDatabase.services.LocalFilesService
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

val NOT_CHIP_ID_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Expected full chip id and NOT with sputter-tray-position: %s";


@RestController

class FileApiController {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var minioService: MinioService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var localFilesService: LocalFilesService


    @GetMapping("/api/files")
    fun getAllFiles(): List<FileMetadata> {
        return minioService.list().map {
            FileMetadata(it,"/api/file/" + it.objectName())
        }
    }

    // other code
}
```

While running project I am getting

```
Field minioService in se.astrego.centralDatabase.apiControllers.FileApiController required a bean of type 'com.jlefebure.spring.boot.minio.MinioService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.jlefebure.spring.boot.minio.MinioService' in your configuration.
```

how to resolve it. any help appreciated